# Let each submodule define its own subparser

Tags: python, argparse

I have to run the main file that depends on the rest of a relatively large project. Project structure can be seen as such

```
main.py
opts.py
--models \
 --model1.py
 --model2.py
 ...
--schedulers
 --scheduler1.py
 --scheduler2.py
 ...
...
```

The problem is when I have to pass arguments to each component (using `argparse`). A simple way would be to define all parameters in a single place for each component. This worked so far for me (in `opts.py`), but I would like to make something more elegant. In my parse function for each component `parse_models` or `parse_scheduler` I would like to iterate through each submodule of `models` and `schedulers` and let them define their own arguments by calling a function `define_arguments` that each of them has where they create their own sub parser.

All in all, how do I iterate through the submodules and call their `define_arguments` function from within `opts.py`?

Comment: Each module could have its own `create_parser` function, that takes a `subparsers` Action object as argument.  Just import the module and run that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the python files using the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) module. You can find the correct path with the parent module's `__path__` attribute. Import the modules using [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module). The imported module then contains the `define_arguments` function that you can pass a parser per submodule to define the arguments on:

```py
from glob import glob
import os, importlib

def load_submodule_parsers(parent_module, parser, help=None):
  if help is None:
    help = parent_module.__name__ + " modules"
  modules = glob(os.path.join(parent_module.__path__, "*.py"))
  subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help=help)
  for module_file in modules:
    module_name = os.path.basename(module_file)[:-3]
    if module == "__init__":
      continue
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name, package=parent_module.__name__)
    if "define_arguments" not in module.__dict__:
      raise ImportError(parent_module.__name__ + " submodule '" + module_name + "' does not have required 'define_arguments' function.")
    parser = subparsers.add_parser(module_name)
    module.define_arguments(parser)
```

Pass the function the parent module object:

```py
import argparse, models, schedulers
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
models_parser = subparsers.add_parser("models")
load_submodule_parsers(models, models_parser)
schedulers_parser = subparsers.add_parser("schedulers")
load_submodule_parsers(schedulers, schedulers_parser)
```

Untested code but I think you can refine it from here

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to iterate through submodules, got that working! The problem now is that subparsers exclude each other, so either it's models or schedulers

Comment: Hmm you'll have to debug that a bit, maybe I'm not passing around the parsers and subparsers correctly. On first glance it looks OK: I make a subparser collection for the root parser and add a parser for the models, and one for the schedulers, then for each another subparser collection is made and each module is added as a parser to it. This should get you all your parsers like this: `my_command models model1` or `my_command schedulers scheduler2`

Comment: It seems I didn't explain it properly, I wanted to be able to do `my_command schedulers scheduler1 models model1` but I'm going to accept your answer since you did answer my original question

Comment: Oh, you'll have to slightly refactor the code then. Maybe the easiest is to collect all the model parsers and then add them all to each scheduler parser.

Comment: I thought of that but I have many more modules so with each new module there will be an exponential increase in parsers. In the end it seems that argparse doesn't really fit my use case so I'll use yaml or json as a config file and use that as input for `main.py`

Comment: argparse also has the `choices` option for arguments, maybe that fits better and you end up with `my_command scheduler1 model2` syntax? You could use the formatted and filtered glob results. You can then make a map of the module name to some sort of handler or instance and retrieve your handlers/instances with the parsed namespace value